# Is it possible to overload "?" operator?

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, operators, new-operator, ternary-operator

I was able to overload `??` operator without much trouble. However, `?` operator keeps resisting. I want to overload it as binary infix operator.

Here is what I did with `??`:

```
infix operator ?? {associativity right precedence 110}
public func ?? (condition: Bool, asignment: @autoclosure () -> ()) {
    ... //some execution
}
```

The same does not work for `?` - if I skip `infix operator ? ...` I get compile error that such operator does not exist. If I include it I get compile error on that line.

Was somebody able to overload it? Or somebody authoritative to (from Swift team?) to confirm that it is not intended to be overloaded? If so, what are the reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't override `?` -- it's a reserved operator in all three positions. From the [Swift language docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-XID_955):

> The tokens `=`, `->`, `//`, `/*`, `*/`, `.`, the prefix operators `<`, `&`, and `?`, the infix operator `?`, and the postfix operators `>`, `!`, and `?` are reserved. These tokens can’t be overloaded, nor can they be used as custom operators.